# Loading a p5js sketch by appending it to the DOM on button press

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

### Background

I'm trying to display multiple versions of the same sketch on the page, so my users can click a button and have the destination div (`#demo`) load up the proper sketch. Right now I'm trying to implement the part where clicked the button inserts the sketch into the DOM.

### What works, what doesn't

Right now I'm able to append the sketch to the DOM and have it render correctly, but I haven't gotten it to work after the button press.

##### This works, but isn't what I want

Here I'm appending the script without waiting for the button press, and it renders correctly, including creating the canvas in the DOM.

```
const demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo");
const circuitButton = document.getElementById("circuit");

function loadScript(tileset) {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "scripts/demo.js";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.setAttribute("tileset", tileset);
  demoDiv.appendChild(script);
}

loadScript("circuit");

// circuitButton.addEventListener("click", () => loadScript("circuit"));
```

[image: DOM contains canvas]

##### This is what I want, but doesn't work

```
const demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo");
const circuitButton = document.getElementById("circuit");

function loadScript(tileset) {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "scripts/demo.js";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.setAttribute("tileset", tileset);
  demoDiv.appendChild(script);
}

// loadScript("circuit");

circuitButton.addEventListener("click", () => loadScript("circuit"));
```

I would think I would be able to append the script into the DOM and have the sketch run the same way as in the prior example, but lo, it was not to be.

After pressing the button, the script has been added to the DOM, but the sketch does not render (nor is the canvas added to the DOM).

[image: No canvas in the DOM]

### What I've tried / My thoughts

I tried manually creating a canvas element at the same time as the script, making sure it matched the specifics of the canvas shown in the first image. I was able to create a matching canvas, but that didn't magically solve my problem.

That leads me to assume that some things that happen when I call `loadScript` in the script execution itself (maybe because it's on page load), that don't happen when I'm appending the script into the DOM later (i.e. creating the canvas object in the DOM and, y'know, drawing on it.)

### Tl;dr / Summary

Is there a difference in adding a script to the DOM on page load compared to in a callback function on an event?

Is there a way I can make my sketch "begin running" after I've put it into the DOM?

Thanks for any and all help!

### The Rest of the code

(pardon the mess)
[GitHub repo](https://github.com/JoePShoulak/wave-function-collapse) for absolutely all of it.
[Pages deployment](https://joepshoulak.github.io/wave-function-collapse/) as well, in case that's helpful to anyone.

##### Demo.js

```
const tileset = document.currentScript.getAttribute("tileset");

const parent = document.querySelector("#demo");
const width = 500;
const height = 500;
// const width = parent.clientWidth;
// const height = parent.clientHeight;

const tilesetDict = {
  "circuit-joe": { mode: "complex", length: 19 },
  circuit: { mode: "simple", length: 13 },
  lines: { mode: "simple", length: 2 },
  polka: { mode: "simple", length: 2 },
  roads: { mode: "simple", length: 2 },
  "train-tracks": { mode: "complex", length: 2 },
  "circuit-coding-train": { mode: "simple", length: 13 },
  "circuit-custom": { mode: "complex", length: 17 },
};

/* == VARIABLES == */
const GRID_SCALE = 1 / 40; // 1/3 is in deployment
const SHOW_DRAW = true;
const LOOP_DELAY = 10 * 1000; // ms
const mode = tilesetDict[tileset].mode;
let images;
let waveFunction;

/* == HELPER FUNCTION == */
function drawCell(cell) {
  const w = width / waveFunction.width;
  const h = height / waveFunction.height;

  const cells = [cell, ...Object.values(cell.neighbors)];

  cells.forEach((cell) => {
    const img = cell.state?.img;
    const pos = [cell.x * w, cell.y * h];
    const size = [w, h];

    img ? image(img, ...pos, ...size) : rect(...pos, ...size);
  });
}

const loadAllImages = (folder, number) => {
  const imgs = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    imgs.push(loadImage(`../tiles/${folder}/${i}.png`));
  }

  return imgs;
};

function rotateImg(img, amount) {
  const w = img.width;
  const h = img.height;

  const newImg = createGraphics(w, h);

  newImg.imageMode(CENTER);
  newImg.translate(w / 2, h / 2);
  newImg.rotate(HALF_PI * amount);
  newImg.image(img, 0, 0);

  return new Tile(newImg);
}

/* == MAIN FUNCTIONS == */
function reset() {
  background("black");
  waveFunction.reset();
  loop();
}

function preload() {
  const length = tilesetDict[tileset].length;
  images = loadAllImages(tileset, length);
}

function setup() {
  Tile.rotateImg = rotateImg;
  Tile.fullEdgeDetection = mode == "complex";
  Cell.resetCallback = (cell) => drawCell(cell);
  Cell.setOptions(images);

  const canvas = createCanvas(width, height);
  canvas.parent("demo");
  fill("black");
  background("black");
  noStroke();

  waveFunction = new Grid(
    floor(width * GRID_SCALE),
    floor(height * GRID_SCALE)
  );
}

function draw() {
  if (SHOW_DRAW) {
    if (!waveFunction.collapsed) {
      const newCell = waveFunction.observe();
      drawCell(newCell);
    } else {
      setTimeout(reset, LOOP_DELAY);
      noLoop();
    }
  } else {
    waveFunction.collapse();
    waveFunction.cells.forEach((cell) => drawCell(cell));
    noLoop();
  }
}
```

##### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title>WFC - Home</title>

    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
    <link
      href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Cantarell:ital,wght@1,700&family=Roboto&display=swap"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/style.css" />

    <script src="../libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../libraries/waveFunctionCollapse.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <article>
      <h1>Wave Function Collapse</h1>
      <hr />
      <h3>What is that?</h3>

      <p>
        I should start by saying I didn't come up with it. I also can't say that
        I fully understand all of the thought that went in to it, or some of its
        subleties. For the utmost in detail, please check out the original work
        <a href="https://github.com/mxgmn/WaveFunctionCollapse" target="_blank">
          here </a
        >.
      </p>
      <p>
        Wave Function Collapse is an algorithm that alows us to, for example,
        generate an image made of a tiling of smaller images with rules for
        which images may be adjacent. By guessing where we have to and updating
        our neighbors' legal options after each guess, we're able to generate a
        reasonable potential image. By identifying and correcting any eventual
        mistakes, we can assure the final product is a "legal" image.
      </p>
      <p>
        The algorithm gets its name from Quantum Mechanics, where our cells are
        in superposition of multiple states, and by observing our cells we are
        able to collapse that superposition, revealing more information about
        the state of the cells around us, and eventually leading to the entropic
        collapse of the entire system.
      </p>

      <h3>Uh huh... Yeah, I know some of those words...</h3>

      <p>
        Err, right. Yeah. This is more of a visual thing. Luckily, I have
        visuals! Check these out and we'll keep talking about this after.
      </p>

      <h4>Simple</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="wfc/lines.html">Lines</a></li>
        <li><a href="wfc/polka.html">Polka</a></li>
        <li><a href="wfc/roads.html">Roads</a></li>
        <li><a href="wfc/train-tracks.html">Train Tracks</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="demo">
        <!-- <script src="scripts/demo.js" tileset="circuit"></script> -->
      </div>

      <h4>Complex</h4>
      <ul>
        <li><button id="circuit">Circuit - Original</button></li>
        <li><a href="wfc/circuit-modified.html">Circuit - Modified</a></li>
        <li><a href="wfc/circuit-custom.html">Circuit - Custom</a></li>
      </ul>

      <h3>Okay, I saw what was happening... tell me what that means again?</h3>
      <p>So the process goes like this:</p>
      <h4>The Setup</h4>
      <ol>
        <li>
          Define a grid that's X units by Y units, called "cells". This will
          hold our images eventually.
        </li>
        <li>
          Define a set of possible images for our options called "tiles", as
          well as the rules for how these tiles can connect to each other.
        </li>
        <li>
          Tell every cell in the grid that, by default, they are allowed to be
          any of the options.
        </li>
      </ol>
      <h4>The Algorithm</h4>
      <p>
        Now that we've set up our system, we can perform our algorithm over and
        over until our system is solved.
      </p>
      <ol>
        <li>
          Find the cell with the smallest number of available options.
          <ul>
            <li>If there's several tied for the lowest, pick one at random.</li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>
          "Collapse" the cell by assigning its state to one of its options at
          random.
        </li>
        <li>
          Tell all the neighbor cells their list of legal options is now reduced
          to those matching this new cell.
          <ul>
            <li>
              If any of those neighbors have their options reduced to zero,
              reset that neighbor and all of its neighbors.
            </li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Repeat until all cells have been collapsed!</li>
      </ol>

      <h3>How do the tiles know what they're alowed to be next to?</h3>
      <p>
        Great question! You can provide rules for the tiles that explicitly say
        which tile edges are allowed to go next to each other. My code checks
        the pixels on the edges of the images and stores that to compare against
        the other images, so it detects the rules automatically!
      </p>
      <p>
        This doesn't always work: not all tilesets can have their rules
        explained perfectly by a single method. Or at least, if there is one
        such method, I haven't found it yet. But so long as the edges of each
        matched image are identical, this algorithm will understand that as a
        rule.
      </p>

      <h3>
        Got it... I think. Is this useful though? It definitely looks cool...
      </h3>
      <p>
        Yes! I mean, maybe not to everyone, but we can definitely find places
        where this algorithm could come in handy. One example is creating video
        game textures! Maybe you want to have a bunch of backgrounds for your
        levels that should be similar, but not the same. Instead of sitting
        there arranging all the tiles by hand!
      </p>
      <p>
        Let's come up with a more entertaining example though. What if instead
        of watching these images get drawn, we hid the whole process, and before
        revealing the image, we rotated some of the tiles and allowed the user
        to rotate them back by clicking.
      </p>
      <p>
        Because we're generating the picture according to the tile rules, we can
        be sure we'll always have a solvable puzzle as opposed to randomly
        placing random tiles in random directions.
      </p>
      <p>
        Oh and look! That game we just talked about is right here!
        <a href="#">Not yet implemented</a>
      </p>
    </article>
    <script src="index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

##### index.js

```
const demoDiv = document.getElementById("demo");
const circuitButton = document.getElementById("circuit");

function loadScript(tileset) {
  const script = document.createElement("script");
  script.src = "scripts/demo.js";
  script.type = "text/javascript";
  script.setAttribute("tileset", tileset);
  demoDiv.appendChild(script);
}

// loadScript("circuit");

circuitButton.addEventListener("click", () => loadScript("circuit"));
```

##### Not Shown

`waveFunctionCollapse.js` is the library I made for computing all the things the sketch is drawing. If that's part of the problem, I have more problems than I thought!

Comment: Can you show demo.js and more of the complete setup instead of the bits you've chosen here?

Comment: @morganney I added those files and linked to the repo and deployment. Sorry, I should have come up with a Minimal Reprodicble Example.

Comment: Have you confirmed whether this is a browser cache issue? If so try cache busting by adding a random query string when reloading demo.js.

Comment: So, I actually got the script to correctly render by using instance mode (linked at the end), but now the sketches are interfering with each other, as if they're not being properly overwritten. 

I'm waiting until I have a slightly better handle on what's happening before I self-answer and close. 

https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/p5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the script to correctly render by using p5's "[instance mode](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/p5)."

Unfortunately, other issues arose and I realized that iframes did exactly what I wanted them to do in this instance, so I switched to that and made this question irrelevant to my moving forward, haha.

So the answer may also be to consider using iframes instead. It really was quite painless.